# Sum of multiple columns SQL

Tags: sql

I have student mark data set as below

```
RegNo Subj1 Mark1 Subj2 Mark2 Subj3 Mark3 Subj4 Mark4
```

Where Subj is the subject name and the Mark given.

The data is such that, the same subject may be in any of the columns for different students. Eg. Student1 may have chosen Eng as Subj1 where as Student2 may have chosen as Subj2.

Now I require the Average of each subject. How do I find?

Comment: which rdbms are you using?

Comment: You should normalize your data model, then your problem is reduced to a very simple and basic `group by` aggregate query.

Answer (score 8):

Your should fix your data structure.  Normally, when you have columns that contains the same data and are only distinguished by numbers at the end, you have a bad structure.  You want a table that looks like:

```
Regno Subj Mark
```

with one row per student and `subj`.  This is called a junction table, and part of the process of normalizing the data.

You can create one on the fly for this query, but you should really fix the data structure:

```
select subj, avg(mark)
from ((select regno, subj1 as subj, mark1 as mark from studentmark) union all
      (select regno, subj2 as subj, mark2 as mark from studentmark) union all
      (select regno, subj3 as subj, mark3 as mark from studentmark) union all
      (select regno, subj4 as subj, mark4 as mark from studentmark)
     ) sm
group by sub;
```

Sample in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0ed33/3).

Comment: Took the liberty to add the fiddle demo.

Answer (score 1):

You can compute a `UNION` of the four cases of the subject being in each of the four columns. For example:

```
SELECT RegNo, Subj1 as Subj, Mark1 as Mark from NormalizeMePlease where Subj1='SQL basics'
UNION
SELECT RegNo, Subj2 as Subj, Mark2 as Mark from NormalizeMePlease where Subj2='SQL basics'
UNION
SELECT RegNo, Subj3 as Subj, Mark3 as Mark from NormalizeMePlease where Subj3='SQL basics'
UNION
SELECT RegNo, Subj4 as Subj, Mark4 as Mark from NormalizeMePlease where Subj4='SQL basics'
```

It could be turned into a view for convenience. Selecting the average or anything else from properly structured data should be easy.